# How to find files or folders using regular expression from list of paths

Tags: java

Assume i am having the following paths in the database

```
Emp/Test/
Emp/bi testing/1.txt
Emp/bi testing/2.txt
Emp/bi testing/1/pipe.txt
Emp/Test/Raj/
Emp/Test/Raj/1.txt
Emp/Test/Somu/
Emp/Test/Pr/
Emp/Test/R.txt
Emp/Test/P.txt
```

I need help to build regular expressions

1. To list all the files and folders for the given path without one more level sub-directories or sub-directories file excluding the given folder path.

example input: Emp/Test/

example output:

```
Emp/Test/Raj/
Emp/Test/Somu/
Emp/Test/Pr/
Emp/Test/R.txt
Emp/Test/P.txt
```

2. To list all the files and folders for the given path including sub-directories and sub-directories files except the given folder path.

example input: Emp/Test/

example output:

```
Emp/Test/Raj/
Emp/Test/Raj/1.txt
Emp/Test/Somu/
Emp/Test/Pr/
Emp/Test/R.txt
Emp/Test/P.txt
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "in the database", could this have an SQL solution (rather than Java as you have tagged it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case 1 : You should have something like :

`Emp\/Test\/(\w+\.\w+|([\w]+\/{1}))\n`

For the case 2, there is only a plus to match multiple time the recursive directories.

`Emp\/Test\/(\w+\.\w+|([\w]+\/{1}))+\n`

Explanations:

- `Emp/Test/` has been converted to 'Emp/Test/' to escape the character `/`.
- `\w+\.\w+` match a file.
- `[\w]+\/{1}`match a directory
- the final `+` stands for applying multiple times the previous group.
- `\n` is a newline

Comment: The first one results only Emp/Test/Somu/ which is wrong

Comment: Thanks a lot Didier..Can you please give me a similar working example for case 2

Comment: Just add the plus inside the regex: https://regex101.com/r/L7E5e6/2, and think to flag as solved if your problem does not exist anymore.